# Error in collections

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, collection

I had an error like below,

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 5 passed to
 Webkul\Pos\Model\ResourceModel\Agent\Collection::__construct() must be
 an instance of Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection, null given,
 called in
```

**/var/www/sqdelivery/generated/code/Webkul/Pos/Model/ResourceModel/Agent/Collection/Interceptor.php**
     on line 14 and defined in

**/var/www/sqdelivery/app/code/Webkul/Pos/Model/ResourceModel/Agent/Collection.php:31**
     Stack trace: #0

**/var/www/sqdelivery/generated/code/Webkul/Pos/Model/ResourceModel/Agent/Collection/Interceptor.php(14):**

```
 Webkul\Pos\Model\ResourceModel\Agent\Collection->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactory), Object(Magento\Framework\Logger\Monolog),
 Object(Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategy\Query),
 Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy), NULL, NULL) #1
```

**/var/www/sqdelivery/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(111):**

```
 Webkul\Pos\Model\ResourceModel\Agent\Collection\Interceptor->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFac
 in
 **/var/www/sqdelivery/app/code/Webkul/Pos/Model/ResourceModel/Agent/Collection.php
 on line 31**
```

what is does means.??
My Collection file code is below,

```
<?php

namespace Webkul\Pos\Model\ResourceModel\Agent;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection  {

     const AGENT_MODEL_NAME = Webkul\Pos\Model\Agent::class;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\DataObject\Copy\Config
 */
protected $_fieldsetConfig;

/**
 * @var string
 */
protected $_modelName;

     public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactory $entityFactory,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
    \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
    \Magento\Framework\Validator\UniversalFactory $universalFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\VersionControl\Snapshot $entitySnapshot,
    \Magento\Framework\DataObject\Copy\Config $fieldsetConfig,
    \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null,
    $modelName = self::AGENT_MODEL_NAME
) {
    $this->_fieldsetConfig = $fieldsetConfig;
    $this->_modelName = $modelName;
    parent::__construct(
        $entityFactory,
        $logger,
        $fetchStrategy,
        $eventManager,
        $eavConfig,
        $resource,
        $eavEntityFactory,
        $resourceHelper,
        $universalFactory,
        $entitySnapshot,
        $connection
    );
}

    protected $_idFieldName = "id";



    protected function _construct()  {
        $this->_init("Webkul\Pos\Model\Agent", "Webkul\Pos\Model\ResourceModel\Agent");
        $this->_map["fields"]["id"] = "main_table.id";
    }

    public function setAgentData($condition, $attributeData)  {
        return $this->getConnection()->update($this->getTable("pos_agent"), $attributeData, $where = $condition);
    }

    public function addNameToSelect()
   {
    $fields = [];

    $agentAccount = $this->_fieldsetConfig->getFieldset('agent_account');
     print_r($agentAccount);
     exit;

    foreach ($agentAccount as $code => $field) {
        if (isset($field['email'])) {
            $fields[$code] = $code;
        }
    }

    $connection = $this->getConnection();
    $concatenate = [];
    if (isset($fields['prefix'])) {
        $concatenate[] = $connection->getCheckSql(
            '{{prefix}} IS NOT NULL AND {{prefix}} != \'\'',
            $connection->getConcatSql(['LTRIM(RTRIM({{prefix}}))', '\' \'']),
            '\'\''
        );
    }
    $concatenate[] = 'LTRIM(RTRIM({{firstname}}))';
    $concatenate[] = '\' \'';
    if (isset($fields['middlename'])) {
        $concatenate[] = $connection->getCheckSql(
            '{{middlename}} IS NOT NULL AND {{middlename}} != \'\'',
            $connection->getConcatSql(['LTRIM(RTRIM({{middlename}}))', '\' \'']),
            '\'\''
        );
    }
    $concatenate[] = 'LTRIM(RTRIM({{lastname}}))';
    if (isset($fields['suffix'])) {
        $concatenate[] = $connection->getCheckSql(
            '{{suffix}} IS NOT NULL AND {{suffix}} != \'\'',
            $connection->getConcatSql(['\' \'', 'LTRIM(RTRIM({{suffix}}))']),
            '\'\''
        );
    }

    $nameExpr = $connection->getConcatSql($concatenate);

    $this->addExpressionAttributeToSelect('name', $nameExpr, $fields);

    return $this;
    }

public function getSelectCountSql()
{
    $select = parent::getSelectCountSql();
    $select->resetJoinLeft();

    return $select;
}

/**
 * Reset left join
 *
 * @param int $limit
 * @param int $offset
 * @return \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection
 */
protected function _getAllIdsSelect($limit = null, $offset = null)
{
    $idsSelect = parent::_getAllIdsSelect($limit, $offset);
    $idsSelect->resetJoinLeft();
    return $idsSelect;
}

}
```

Anyone please help me to slove this error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: don't forget to execute `bin/magento setup:upgrade` after finished edit your construct class

Answer (score 0):

Your construct should be

```
public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactory $entityFactory,
\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
\Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
\Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
\Magento\Framework\Validator\UniversalFactory $universalFactory,
\Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\VersionControl\Snapshot $entitySnapshot,
\Magento\Framework\DataObject\Copy\Config $fieldsetConfig,
\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null,
$modelName = self::AGENT_MODEL_NAME
 ) {
$this->_fieldsetConfig = $fieldsetConfig;
$this->_modelName = $modelName;
parent::__construct(
    $entityFactory,
    $logger,
    $fetchStrategy,
    $eventManager,
    $resource,
    $universalFactory,
    $entitySnapshot,
    $connection
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the __contruct like below:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactory $entityFactory,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
    \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
    \Magento\Framework\Validator\UniversalFactory $universalFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\VersionControl\Snapshot $entitySnapshot,
    \Magento\Framework\DataObject\Copy\Config $fieldsetConfig,
    \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null,
    $modelName = self::AGENT_MODEL_NAME
) {
    $this->_fieldsetConfig = $fieldsetConfig;
    $this->_modelName = $modelName;
    parent::__construct(
        $entityFactory,
        $logger,
        $fetchStrategy,
        $eventManager,
        $connection,
        $resource
    );
}
```

Because if you see the parent class **AbstractCollection** , it has only 6 parameters(see below):

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
    ) {
        $this->_eventManager = $eventManager;
        parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $connection);
        $this->_construct();
        $this->_resource = $resource;
        $this->setConnection($this->getResource()->getConnection());
        $this->_initSelect();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<?php

namespace Webkul\Pos\Model\ResourceModel\Agent;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection  {

    const AGENT_MODEL_NAME = Webkul\Pos\Model\Agent::class;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\DataObject\Copy\Config
     */
    protected $_fieldsetConfig;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resourceConnection,
        \Magento\Framework\DataObject\Copy\Config $fieldsetConfig
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $entityFactory,
            $logger,
            $fetchStrategy,
            $eventManager,
            $connection
            $resource
        );
        $this->_fieldsetConfig = $fieldsetConfig;
        $this->resourceConnection = $resourceConnection;
        $this->setConnection($this->resourceConnection->getConnection());
    }

    protected $_idFieldName = "id";



    protected function _construct()  {
        $this->_init("Webkul\Pos\Model\Agent", "Webkul\Pos\Model\ResourceModel\Agent");
        $this->_map["fields"]["id"] = "main_table.id";
    }

    public function setAgentData($condition, $attributeData)  {
        return $this->getConnection()->update($this->getTable("pos_agent"), $attributeData, $where = $condition);
    }

   public function addNameToSelect()
   {
        $fields = [];

        $agentAccount = $this->_fieldsetConfig->getFieldset('agent_account');
         print_r($agentAccount);
         exit;

        foreach ($agentAccount as $code => $field) {
            if (isset($field['email'])) {
                $fields[$code] = $code;
            }
        }

        $connection = $this->getConnection();
        $concatenate = [];
        if (isset($fields['prefix'])) {
            $concatenate[] = $connection->getCheckSql(
                '{{prefix}} IS NOT NULL AND {{prefix}} != \'\'',
                $connection->getConcatSql(['LTRIM(RTRIM({{prefix}}))', '\' \'']),
                '\'\''
            );
        }
        $concatenate[] = 'LTRIM(RTRIM({{firstname}}))';
        $concatenate[] = '\' \'';
        if (isset($fields['middlename'])) {
            $concatenate[] = $connection->getCheckSql(
                '{{middlename}} IS NOT NULL AND {{middlename}} != \'\'',
                $connection->getConcatSql(['LTRIM(RTRIM({{middlename}}))', '\' \'']),
                '\'\''
            );
        }
        $concatenate[] = 'LTRIM(RTRIM({{lastname}}))';
        if (isset($fields['suffix'])) {
            $concatenate[] = $connection->getCheckSql(
                '{{suffix}} IS NOT NULL AND {{suffix}} != \'\'',
                $connection->getConcatSql(['\' \'', 'LTRIM(RTRIM({{suffix}}))']),
                '\'\''
            );
        }

        $nameExpr = $connection->getConcatSql($concatenate);

        $this->addExpressionAttributeToSelect('name', $nameExpr, $fields);

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSelectCountSql()
    {
        $select = parent::getSelectCountSql();
        $select->resetJoinLeft();

        return $select;
    }

    /**
     * Reset left join
     *
     * @param int $limit
     * @param int $offset
     * @return \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection
     */
    protected function _getAllIdsSelect($limit = null, $offset = null)
    {
        $idsSelect = parent::_getAllIdsSelect($limit, $offset);
        $idsSelect->resetJoinLeft();
        return $idsSelect;
    }

}
```

**Note :** please remove the generated folder and cleaned cache after replacing a code